# How to rerun docker-compose after modifying containerized python script

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Docker newbie question here.

I am working on containerizing my own Python script, following [this tutorial](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/) and [that tutorial](https://dev.to/davidsabine/docker-compose-hello-world-1p14).

I noticed that when I fix an error in my Python script (**myscript.py**), this change is not seen upon rerunning `sudo docker-compose up`. I need to change the app name in **docker-compose.yml** (*e.g.* from **my-awesome-app2** to **my-awesome-app3**) to get it to run.

I tried listing the available containers using `sudo docker container ls -a` and then removing the unused containers with `sudo docker rm <CONTAINER ID>` but this did not help.

How can I get docker-compose to see the changes made to the Python script, without having to keep changing the Dockerfile?

---

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-awesome-app3:
    build:
      context: .
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8.3
# Or any preferred Python version.
ADD myscript.py .
RUN pip3 install pywavelets scipy 
CMD ["python", "./myscript.py"] 
# Or enter the name of your unique directory and parameter set.
```

And here is **myscript.py**:

```
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram

import pywt
import numpy as np
ecg = electrocardiogram()
FPData = ecg.reshape(10800,-1)
DWTcoeffs = pywt.wavedec(FPData[:,1], 'db4')
filtered_data_dwt=pywt.waverec(DWTcoeffs,'db4',mode='symmetric',axis=-1)
print(filtered_data_dwt)
```

Let's say that I make a typo (`print(filtered_data)` instead of `print(filtered_data_dwt)`)... Rerunning `sudo docker-compose up` will still trigger:

> my-awesome-app2_1  | NameError: name 'filtered_data' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough reputation for a comment, but did you rebuild your container?

`sudo docker compose up --rebuild` is one way of doing both in one go.

P.S. depending on your security restrictions, [you can set it up](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) to run without the need to prefix it with `sudo`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It got me to check out the different `docker-compose` options available. `sudo docker compose up --rebuild` did not run, but `sudo docker-compose up --build` did the trick.